# Dúvida com GROUP BY - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma consulta ao meu banco de dados, onde ele me retorna várias linhas e agrupa para que me exiba uma só. Porém, existe uma coluna chamada "validado", com a maioria dos valores definidos como "Sim". Gostaria que caso existisse ao menos 1 valor "Não", ele aponte a coluna "validado" no GROUP BY como "Não" também.

```
SELECT assessor, 
       broker, 
       cod_cliente, 
       data_compra, 
       data_inicial, 
       id, 
       nome_cliente, 
       papel, 
       preco, 
       quantidade, 
       squad, 
       validado 
  FROM carteira_perspectiva 
 WHERE (broker = "Eric")
    GROUP BY cod_cliente
```

Comment: não entendi bem, mas se quer fazer um "group by condicional" isso não é possível

Comment: Seria se ao menos um dos valores do grupo for "Não", ele trazer esse valores.

Ou então priorizar os valores "Não".

Acha que não é possível então?

Comment: Não ficou muito claro, mas pelo que pude imaginar você teria que utilizar o CASE statement com uma condição que avalie o código do cliente e se houver um registro "Não" ele replica "Não" para todos os registros respectivos daquele cliente. Dessa forma quando você agrupar ele vai demonstrar "Não validado" porque houve um ou mais registros de "Não" para aquele cod_cliente.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo.. Você consegue escrever como ficaria o código? Mas seria exatamente isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito clara a sua pergunta, não entendi direito. Mas você pode usar a clausula HAVING que permite que você faça um tipo de WHERE no GROUP BY. Exemplo

```
SELECT sum(valor), nome_cliente
FROM compras
GROUP BY nome_cliente
HAVING sum(valor) > 500
```

Nesse caso ele ira fazer uma consulta na tabela de compras, retornando a soma de todas as compras do cliente e o nome dele, fazendo um filtro pelos clientes que gastaram mais de 500 reais no total. Não sei se ficou muito claro.

Você também pode criar uma `PROCEDURE` e fazer todo o processamento lá dentro.

Ou também você pode fazer uma pré-consulta e depois processar ela. Irei usar o mesmo exemplo que dei usei acima de retornar os clientes que gastaram mais de 500 reais no total.

```
WITH compras_por_cliente as (
    SELECT sum(valor), nome_cliente
    FROM compras
    GROUP BY nome_cliente
)

SELECT *
FROM compras_por_cliente 
WHERE valor > 500
```

Nesse caso ele ira criar tipo uma tabela temporária em memória chamada compras_por_cliente com o WITH e depois ira consultar essa tabela temporária no select de baixo.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que um sub-select atenda a necessidade:

```
SELECT assessor, 
       broker, 
       cod_cliente, 
       data_compra, 
       data_inicial, 
       id, 
       nome_cliente, 
       papel, 
       preco, 
       quantidade, 
       squad, 
       (select case when count(X.validado) > 0 then 'Não' else 'Sim' end
            from carteira_perspectiva X
                where X.broker = a.broker
                  and X.cod_cliente = a.cod_cliente
                  and validado = 'Não'
       ) AS 'Validado'
  FROM carteira_perspectiva A
 WHERE (broker = 'Eric')
    GROUP BY cod_cliente
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT assessor, 
       broker, 
       cod_cliente, 
       data_compra, 
       data_inicial, 
       id, 
       nome_cliente, 
       papel, 
       preco, 
       quantidade, 
       squad, 
       CASE 
           WHEN solicitado = 'SIM' THEN 'SIM'
           ELSE 'NÃO'
       END
  FROM carteira_perspectiva 
 WHERE (broker = "Eric")
    GROUP BY cod_cliente
```